# Two column CSS flexbox not responding to 800px media query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a two column flexbox that turns into 1 column when the max-width is 800 px. The behavior I am trying to recreate is here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_responsive2

I have followed the exact css properties from that tutorial but I am not sure why the media query is not responding to my code.

I have a link to my project here: https://codepen.io/saminaCodes/pen/QWEzBmE?editors=1100

HTML Portion

```
<section class = "section-container">

 <div class = "description">
 <h2> Project Name / Job Title </h2>
 <p> Apple pie cotton candy pie powder jelly pudding caramels sesame snaps. Chupa chups donut brownie 
 chocolate cupcake apple pie lemon drops oat cake. Cupcake cotton candy marshmallow sweet roll halvah 
 lollipop croissant tiramisu </p>

 <hr>

 <p class = "notes">
  <b class = "bold">Date:</b> October 2020 - Present<br>
  <b class = "bold">NOTES:</b> n/a<br>
 </p>

  <a href = "#"> Join organization name>></a>
 </div>


 <div class = "content">

 </div>
 </section>
```

CSS Portion

```
.section-container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.description {
  flex: 40%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.content {
  flex: 60%;
  border: solid 0.25em #FFCC5C;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .description, .content {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well, but you missed a technical error in the `flex` rule in css. You have `flex: wrap` written, but you need to write `flex-wrap: wrap` correctly. For this reason, the above blocks are not wrapped in one column.

It should be like this:

```
.section-container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*is here*/
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `width` instead of `flex`. `flex` requires other parameters like shrink and grow e.g. `flex: 0 1 40%;`

```css
.section-container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.description {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.content {
  width: 60%;
  border: solid 0.25em #FFCC5C;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .description, .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```